# Automoc permission denied

Tags: c++, qt, dependencies, workflow

I am responsible for changing the way we deal with dependencies in our studio. We are developing in C++ under ubuntu and we use Qt v5.7.0.

I was thinking of installing / compiling each dependency on my own machine then making an archive out of it so the coders simply have to unpack each dependency archive, clone our repo and start coding.

This approach works well when I make the dependency archives on my own machine, discard the archive and dependency from my machine and unpack from the dependency archive.

Now when I try to unpack the archives on a different machine, everything works fine, except for Qt. For Qt simply unpacking the archive does not work and I get error messages when compiling:

```
automoc ... permission denied
```

When I reinstall Qt from the runfile (in exactely the same location), it works fine.

I was thinking of a problem related to the owner of the file in the archive... but my ideas fall short from there.

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Look at [QtBinPatcher](https://chocolatey.org/packages/qtbinpatcher).

Comment: There seem to be [this Qt Patcher](http://ftp-developpez.com/qt/binaires/win32/patcher/QtPatcher.7z) as well...

Comment: Any idea where the patch built in Qt lies?

Comment: It's not a Qt module. Qt uses `qt.conf` to adjust paths. It's a [third-party](https://github.com/Fsu0413/QtBinPatcher).